# Сессии, авторизация в Golang

Tags: сессия, golang

Добрый день.
Как использовать сессии и авторизацию в go?
Использую beego, но не въеду http://beego.me/docs/module/session.md

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, что уже попробовали и что именно у вас вызвало проблему?

Comment: Нашёл этот вариант http://godoc.org/github.com/bpowers/seshcookie#RequestSessions.Get , Но как вместо handler := seshcookie.NewSessionHandler(
  &AuthHandler{http.FileServer(contentDir), userDb},
  "session key, preferably a sequence of data from /dev/urandom",
  nil) if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
  log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
 }    подцепить фреймворк beego ?

Comment: @TwoRS, нужно больше информации. Вопрос можно редактировать, пожалуйста добавляйте код в вопрос - иначе ничего не понятно. Посмотрел ссылку - вроде бы всё просто. Не могу понять в чём у вас трудности собственно.

Answer (score 1):

Инициализируем сессии в главной функции

Импорт

```
import (
"github.com/astaxie/beego/session"
)
```

`var globalSessions *session.Manager`

например, так

```
func init() {
globalSessions, _ = session.NewManager("memory", `{"cookieName":"sessId", "enableSetCookie,omitempty": true, "gclifetime":3600, "maxLifetime": 3600, "secure": false, "sessionIDHashFunc": "sha1", "sessionIDHashKey": "", "cookieLifeTime": 3600, "providerConfig": ""}`)
    go globalSessions.GC()
}
```

Параметры NewManager можно посмотреть в документации beego

> http://beego.me/docs/module/session.md

Теперь в контролере можно использовать сессии

```
func (c *AnyController) Get() {
        sess, err := globalSessions.SessionStart(c.Ctx.ResponseWriter, c.Ctx.Request)
        defer sess.SessionRelease(c.Ctx.ResponseWriter)
        err := sess.Set("key", "value")
        err = sess.Delete("key")
        //и другие методы
}
```